# How to make conditional formatting work in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
Invoice number
.5
.3
02
```

I want to replace the '.' because it gets captured incorrectly. This is succesful with the following code:

```
df['Invoice number'] = df['Invoice number'].astype(str).str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\$?!]", '')
```

however, a 0 is placed in front of the number resulting in the following df:

```
Invoice number
05
03
02
```

I've tried the following

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if str(i).startswith('.'):  
        df.loc[i, 'KvK'] = df['KvK'].astype(str).str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\$]", '')
        df.loc[i,'Factuurnummer'] = df['Factuurnummer'].astype(str).str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\$]", '')
```

However, this does not work. Nothing happens.

I would like the following output:

```
invoice # 
5
3
02
```

Comment: Are the values in the column integer or string?

Comment: for invoice number it is string

Comment: Try looping through the column and removing the first character/index of the string. Something like `for x in df['Invoice Number']: x = x[1:0]`

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with a mask created by `series.str.startswith` and `series.mask` or `np.where`:

```
s = df['Invoice number']
s.mask(s.str.startswith('.'),s.str.replace(".",""))
```

Or if one is comfortable using a `regex` pattern, one can also use:

```
df['Invoice number'].str.replace(r'^\.', '')
```

---

```
0     5
1     3
2    02
Name: Invoice number, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you @anky! This works ! Do you have any idea why my code does not work? In order to learn

Comment: @Max I am not too comfortable using regex patterns, especially when one can avoid patterns , hence cannot comment on the same.